# Difference on parameter usage in query, using square bracket and not

Tags: python, flask, sqlite

I have the following route function in flask framework:

```
@app.route('/edit/<contact_id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def edit_contact(contact_id):
    db = get_db()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        db.execute('UPDATE contacts SET organization=?, contactPerson=?, phoneNumber=?, email=?, address=? WHERE  id=?',
                   [request.form['organization'], request.form['contactPerson'],
                    request.form['phoneNumber'], request.form['email'],
                    request.form['address'], contact_id])
        db.commit()
        flash('Contact successfully edited')
        return redirect(url_for('select_contact', contact_id=contact_id))
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        cur = db.execute(
            'SELECT id, organization, contactPerson, phoneNumber, email, address FROM contacts ORDER BY organization ASC ')
        contacts = cur.fetchall()

        cur = db.execute('SELECT id, organization, contactPerson, phoneNumber, email, address '
                         'FROM contacts '
                         'WHERE id=? ', [contact_id])
        selected_contact = cur.fetchall()

        disabled = ' '
        edit_cancel = 'cancel'

        return render_template('contacts_list.html', contacts=contacts, selected_contact=selected_contact[0], disabled=disabled, edit_cancel=edit_cancel)
    return redirect(url_for('contacts_list'))
`
```

**The code is working** but I am confused in the usage of parameter *contact_id* in the code.

For the *POST* part I can execute the following SQLite query:

```
db.execute('UPDATE contacts SET organization=?, contactPerson=?, phoneNumber=?, email=?, address=? WHERE  id=?',
                   [request.form['organization'], request.form['contactPerson'],
                    request.form['phoneNumber'], request.form['email'],
                    request.form['address'], contact_id])
```

And for the *GET* part I can execute the following SQLite query:

```
cur = db.execute('SELECT id, organization, contactPerson, phoneNumber, email, address '
                         'FROM contacts '
                         'WHERE id=? ', [contact_id])
```

At first, I was using *[contact_id]* for the *POST* conditional but when I used the *contact_id* using square bracket then the flask will return an error:

> **sqlite3.InterfaceError**
>
> > sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 5 - probably unsupported type.

My question is why does the parameter usage differ in the two query execution above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usage does not differ - in both cases, you're passing a list of variables to `db.execute()`. It just so happens that your `SELECT` statement only has one parameter in the SQL statement (i.e. a list of length 1), whereas your `UPDATE` statement has several (a longer list).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any different with the usage.
Both are enclosed in brackets.

The `POST` method just has a lot of parameters compared to the `GET` method.